# Compilation Error - Open CV project in Eclipse(Windows7)

Tags: opencv, compilation

I am trying to build a simple Open CV project with Eclipse IDE for c/c++ in Windows7. I followed the instructions from here [Building OpenCV projects in Eclipse](http://carrierfrequency.blogspot.in/2011/05/opencv-22-in-windows-using-eclipse-ide.html)
. But I am getting the following error after running the given code:

```
#include "opencv/cv.h"      // include it to used Main OpenCV functions.
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp" //include it to use GUI functions.


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
int iscolor = -1; /* Used to load the image as it is*/

IplImage* img = cvLoadImage((const char *)"er1.jpg", iscolor);//change the name    (image.jpg) according to your Image filename.
cvNamedWindow( "Example1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
cvShowImage("Example1", img);
cvWaitKey(0);
cvReleaseImage( &img );
cvDestroyWindow( "Example1" );
return 0;}
```

Error:

```
 D:\Open_CV_Codes\FirstOpenCV\Debug/../src/FirstOpenCV.c:19: undefined reference to `cvLoadImage'
 D:\Open_CV_Codes\FirstOpenCV\Debug/../src/FirstOpenCV.c:20: undefined reference to `cvNamedWindow'
 D:\Open_CV_Codes\FirstOpenCV\Debug/../src/FirstOpenCV.c:21: undefined reference to `cvShowImage'
 D:\Open_CV_Codes\FirstOpenCV\Debug/../src/FirstOpenCV.c:22: undefined reference to `cvWaitKey'
 D:\Open_CV_Codes\FirstOpenCV\Debug/../src/FirstOpenCV.c:23: undefined reference to `cvReleaseImage'
 D:\Open_CV_Codes\FirstOpenCV\Debug/../src/FirstOpenCV.c:24: undefined reference to `cvDestroyWindow'
 collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
 Build error occurred, build is stopped
```

Comment: Use c++ its much better. 
Second point did you try `#include<opencv/cv.h>` ?

Including with a direct double quotes means there the file should be present in the current directory.

Comment: @SohaibI #include<opencv/cv.h> doesn't work either.